# how to count split words select-string pattern powershell. text file log life .txt .log

Tags: powershell, foreach, split, select-string, group-object

I need to count rows with values ms 2xx (where xx is any number) it can be 200,201,202,258,269 etc. (It has to start with number 2)
Then do it also with numbers 4 and 5.

There In my .txt file with rows like this:

```
2022.10.20 13:42:01.570 | INFO | Executed action "PERPIRestEPService.Controllers.PERPIController.GetVersion (PERPIRestEPService)" in 4.9487ms
2022.10.20 13:42:01.570 | INFO | Executed endpoint '"PERPIRestEPService.Controllers.PERPIController.GetVersion (PERPIRestEPService)"'
2022.10.20 13:42:01.570 | INFO | Request finished in 5.5701ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
2022.10.20 13:42:01.908 | DBUG | Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 4 items
2022.10.20 13:42:01.908 | DBUG | Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.0105ms - processed: 4 items - remaining: 0 items
2022.10.20 13:44:30.632 | DBUG | Received data from rabbit: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<TransactionJournal xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.datapac.sk/Posybe">
  <Header>
    <GeneratedDate>2022-10-20T13:44:30.5409065+02:00</GeneratedDate>
    <BusinessDate>2022-10-20</BusinessDate>
    <SourceSystem>Posybe MCFS</SourceSystem>
    <Site>C702</Site>
    <Version>1.0</Version>
```

I need to make this table. It should look like this:

```
Count Name
----- ----
  97 200
 278 202
   2 205
  18 275
```

I have this code:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\krivosik\Desktop\Scripts\logs\PosybeRestEPService\*.log"
#Write-Host $files
$files | 
    Select-String -Pattern 'ms 2','ms 4' | 
    Group-Object Pattern -NoElement
    #| Select-Object Count, Name 
    
    foreach ($file in $files){
$mss=$file | Select-String -Pattern 'ms 2','ms 4'
    foreach ($l in $mss){
        $s = $l -split(" ")
        $s[9]
        $s[9] | Group-Object | Select-Object Count, Name 
        #Group-Object Pattern -NoElement |
        #Select-String -Pattern 'ms 2','ms 4'
    } 
}
```

I tried to split the row and now I have just the numbers I want to. Now I have to count them and make that table but I dont know how. I should be using Group-object but It just does not work for me.
This is the only output I can get from this code:

```
Count Name                     
----- ----                     
 1463 ms 2                     
    1 ms 4                     
202

Count : 1
Name  : 202

202

Count : 1
Name  : 202

202

Count : 1
Name  : 202

202

Count : 1
Name  : 202
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Group-Object` is the right solution in this scenario. You just have to group by the value that was matched for the name, this way it accounts for the total count of how many were found with that pattern:

```
Select-String -Path 'C:\Users\krivosik\Desktop\Scripts\logs\PosybeRestEPService\*.log' -Pattern '(?<=\d.*?ms )(2|4|5)\d+' | 
    Group-Object -Property { $_.Matches.Value } -NoElement
```

As for the pattern matching, use a "*positive lookbehind*" to ensure the capture of what would be the *name* property, making it less error-prone in case something else down the line matches `ms 2/4/5`.

- *Postive LookBehind*: `(?<=\d.*?ms )`, ensures this pattern matches before you can match what follows without actually capturing that match.
- `(2|4|5)\d+`, here is the actual capture of the *name* property with options to match a pattern starting with either `2`,`4`, or `5` only.

Now, `Group-Object` can take the output of `Select-String` and group them by the values matched via `Matches.Value`; i.e. `2xx`,`4xx`,`5xx`.

**Edit**: The path on where these values are found is already exposed via `Select-String` but you have to bring it out using a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.3). Also, if you want to match exact values of *ms 2xx* the regex following the *positive lookbehind* has to be changed to those values:

```
Select-String -Path 'C:\Users\krivosik\Desktop\Scripts\logs\PosybeRestEPService\*.log' -Pattern '(?<=\d.*?ms )(200|202)' | 
    Group-Object -Property { $_.Matches.Value } | 
        Select-Object -Property Count, Name, @{
            Name = 'Path'
            Expression = { $_.Group[0].Path }
        }
```

- The `|` is used as a delimiter for an "*or*" RegEx operator, so it will match exactly 200, **or** 202.

If you want to add more value to match exactly, just separated them by the `|` delimiter inside the `()`.

Comment: Now I need to count how many "ms 200", "ms 202" etc. are in my .txt files. There are 8 .txt files named log1.txt, log2.txt .. and so on. I need to find out in which .txt file is that certain "ms 201" etc. and how many there are

Comment: @MatúšKrivošík, a man of high-class knowing who that is!:) lol see my edit in the post. I've included a way to expose the path using a calculated property. Also, I included how to get exact values of 200, or 202. It's just switching what comes after the positive lookbehind.

Comment: Haha of course. Thanks again, u made all my troubles go away :)) . This is exactly what I wanted. And I had to rename myself to my favourite character as well.